# Spring Boot MVC 2.5.3 Validation apparently not working

Tags: java, spring, validation

I have built a simple rest controller with one endpoint that takes a string that must contain only digits. The signature is

```
    public TestResult getTestNumber(@Valid @NotNull(message = "Number missing")
                                              @NotEmpty(message = "Number cannot be empty")
                                              @Pattern(regexp="^[1-9][0-9]*$",
                                                       message = "Number must be formed only from digits and cannot start with zero")
                                              @RequestParam(value="number")  String value) {
        return testService.calculateNum(value);
    }
```

In the pom.xml I have all required spring dependencies (I think)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

and I do not have any other validation dependencies (javax, hibernate), etc. Still validation does not work. Any ideas? Did I miss anything. Thanks a lot any helpful info.

Comment: This will only work with a model (so you need a wrapper for the string) or use `@Validated` on the controller to have validation applied to individual arguments (however that serves a different purpose than validating model values, and is also handled differently!).

Comment: Adding Validated to controller did not work, where I can see an working example? Thanks

Comment: You also need to register the `MethodValidationPostProcessor` as a `static` `@Bean`. But I would strongly suggest not to go down that path, instead just write a wrapper for your value and place the annotations on the field in there. Much easier and less error prone (and less surprising).